# What kind of C code can be compiled into assembly code like "LDR R3,[R4,#0x18]", where R3 is a pointer

Tags: arm, reverse-engineering, ida

I reversed an ARM firmware with IDA Pro; Some of the assembly code is as follows:

[image: Disassembly code]

---

ROM:08079B00                 MOVS            R1, R0

ROM:08079B02                 BEQ             loc_8079B14

ROM:08079B04                 LDR             R0, [R4,#0x10]

ROM:08079B06                 LDR             R2, [R1,#4]

ROM:08079B08                 SUBS            R0, R0, #3

ROM:08079B0A                 STRH            R0, [R2,#0x10]

ROM:08079B0C                 LDR             R3, [R4,#0x18]

ROM:08079B0E                 LDR             R2, [R4,#0x20]

ROM:08079B10                 LDR             R0, [R5]

ROM:08079B12                 BLX             R3

---

The instruction at offset 0x08079B12 is BLX R3, so R3 is a pointer; The value of R3 comes from the LDR instruction at offset 0x08079B0C (LDR R3,[R4,#0x18]).

What kind of C code can be compiled into assembly code like "LDR R3,[R4,#0x18]", where R3 is a pointer.

Comment: function pointers out of a struct

Comment: Thank you. It is true that the structure contains function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef   int (*fun)(int a , int b );
typedef  struct _str 
{
       int a;
       int b;
       fun op;
} STR;
STR funop;
int fun2 ( int a, int b)
{
    funop.a=a;
    funop.b=b;
    return(funop.op(a,b)+1);
}


00000000 <fun2>:
   0:   e59f3014    ldr r3, [pc, #20]   ; 1c <fun2+0x1c>
   4:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   8:   e5932008    ldr r2, [r3, #8]
   c:   e8830003    stm r3, {r0, r1}
  10:   e12fff32    blx r2
  14:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
  18:   e8bd8010    pop {r4, pc}
  1c:   00000000
```

Just need it to want to use a base plus offset addressing to read the address of a function and then call it.  blx does a call so the value is a function pointer so the code is related to a function pointer.  Without the struct it might not do a base + offset and instead do a pc relative load.

It does not necessarily need to be global.

```
int (*fun)(int a , int b );
int fun2 ( int a, int b)
{
    return((fun)(a,b)+1);
}
00000000 <fun2>:
   0:   e59f3018    ldr r3, [pc, #24]   ; 20 <fun2+0x20>
   4:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   8:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
   c:   e1a0e00f    mov lr, pc
  10:   e12fff13    bx  r3
  14:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  18:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  20:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
```

because I made it global it has to do the double indirect thing so it is still a base plus offset (of zero).

```
int fun3(int a , int b );
int fun2 ( int a, int b)
{
    int (*fun)(int a , int b );
    fun=fun3;
    return((fun)(a,b)+1);
}

00000000 <fun2>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun3>
   8:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
   c:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

The linker fills in the direct offset so no register plus offset addressing.  No ldr at all because it can be handled with the branch link.

I think those are the choices a bl to be resolved at link time or a double indirect of a pool value that is resolved at link time.  Struct or not it is an ldr with a register plus offset (gnu disassembler does not show the offset if zero).

Comment: Please take care with your spellings here, especially words containing apostrophes. Here are some correct spellings, plus the number of mispellings in your post history: don't (765), doesn't (488), can't (306), won't (217), isn't (148). There is some tolerance here for people who don't have English as a first language, but stylistic and deliberate misspelling works against the aims of the site, and is a great deal of work being deliberately made for volunteer editors. Do you have a spell-checker available in your browser?